# Javascript function runs indefinitely when inside for-loop

Tags: javascript

On my page, I am adding `<div>` elements to the page using `javascript`. The content and number of 's comes from the content of a folder on the server. the page have a number of columns and I want to add each new  to the smallest column. I created this function to determine what column is the smallest. When run/tested on a single request the function works as intended. when I call the function inside my "for-loop" with the elements that need to be added it runs indefinitely?

for for-loop is

```
for(i = 0; i < importedElement.length; i++){}
```

the function is

```
function findSmallestColumn() {
    var columns = document.getElementById("container").children;
    var columnsHeight = [];
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++) {
        columnsHeight[i] = columns[i].offsetHeight;
    }
    var min = Math.min(...columnsHeight);
    var minIndex = columnsHeight.indexOf(min) + 1;
    return minIndex;
}
```

*The "numberOfColumns is a var with a number attached.

Comment: You've forgotten the `var` (or `let`) on both definitions of `i`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a second `for` loop inside your function, which infinitely increases `i`. Replace `i` with `j` or any other variable name in any of the two `for` loops and it will work as expected.

You could use the same variable name, `i` if you declare them locally inside the for loop using the `let` keyword, which declares variables only in the current block.

Comment: The reason is that variables in JavaScript are scoped to functions. The for-loop does not provide a new scope. It should work if you re-declare the variable i inside the function.

Comment: Thank you very much! So clear now but I have been staring me blind on this for hours.

Comment: This question is a good example of why you should always use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), it will complain if you forget to declare a variable and save you those hours of frustration. Using a linter also helps a lot with this kind of bug.